# Animated Passive Object Does Not Work With Rigid Body Simulation

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

Animated Passive Object Does Not Work With Rigid Body Simulation. It's bit hard to explain.
[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[Download Blender File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tOtUVwckTTB0VQHyEiP0YsAgUqL3Q9ph/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please read: [How do I ask a question that is hard to describe?](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/608/how-do-i-ask-a-question-that-is-hard-to-describe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got two problems:
 1. You baked the physics simulation, effectively key-framing all objects that are part of it. Baking the simulation is useful if you don't plan on changing the simulation again, but it's not necessary to render an image/animation.
 2. You have two planes which you are trying to animate in the same spot - Plane.003 and Plane.013; they have different settings.

First, free the bake:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbTQu.jpg

Second, set Plane.003 to be animated, or just delete it since it is a duplicate:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/C77Ek.jpg